# You must first build vocabulary Word2vec error

Tags: python, word2vec

When I use `Import word2vec` I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: you must first build vocabulary before training the model`

I tried in python idle and ipython

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or obtain a vector to use with word2vec.

See here:
https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/#Where_to_obtain_the_training_data

And here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/word2vec-toolkit/lxbl_MB29Ic

Comment: I checked that two links.Still am not getting.Kindly help me

Comment: Maybe try this? http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/danielfrg/word2vec/blob/master/examples/word2vec.ipynb